# Can an SKSpriteNode Object be Searched by Name

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

I am creating a game using Apple's SpriteKit, and I am wondering what is the most efficient way to find an SKSpriteNode object after creating it.

In one method I initialize a sprite node and assign a name to it:

```
SKSpriteNode* playerBody = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"playerBody.png"];
playerBody.name = @"player";
```

Later on inside the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method I want to find the previously defined sprite node again and store it so I can run actions on it. First I attempted to do this:

```
SKSpriteNode* body = [self childNodeWithName:@"player"];
```

However, I have realized that `childNodeWithName:` is only available in the `SKNode` class, not `SKSpriteNode`. So this does not work. What I am thinking now is that I can create an `SKNode` object and place my `SKSpriteNode` inside of it. This way I can search for the `SKNode` using the above method. This seems a bit convoluted, however. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SKSpriteNode inherits from SKNode. You can use childNodeWithName.

```
SKSpriteNode *someSprite = [SKSpriteNode node];

[someSprite childNodeWithName:@"someChildOfSprite"];
```

Code for comment below asking how to cast SKNode as an SKSpriteNode:

```
SKSpriteNode *theChildYouWant = (SKSpriteNode*)[someSprite childNodeWithName:@"someChildOfSprite"];
```

Comment: alternatively, `someSprite.children` will also return an array of all nodes the sprite contains.

Comment: Okay, now that you say this it is quite obvious that I should be able to use childNodeWithName. I should have realized that. I have a followup question, then, and this is the reason I was confused in the first place. When I do what you have written above Xcode gives me a warning saying "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'SKSpriteNode*' with an expression of type 'SKNode*'" Is this just some inconsequential warning? In my experience when Xcode shows a warning there is usually a better way to rewrite the code to eliminate it.

Comment: the method childNodeWithName returns an SKNode. You are then trying to   assign that SKNode as an SKSprite, which the compiler will complain about, since you are trying to put an apple into an orange. But you as the coder knows that what the child actually is is an SKSpriteNode. So one step could be to cast the object as an SKSpriteNode. I'll add the code to the answer above.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your time and very clear response.

Comment: but please keep in mind that if you are confused by the concept of casting, it's not some amazing solution. It's just telling the compiler more information, but it doesn't actually change the object. In this way you can actually silence a warning from the compiler, but be lying about what the object really is, causing bad things to happen.

Comment: Duly noted: it works because I already know my code is correct, I'm just satisfying the compiler by casting.